# Mutiny service interface cannot be injected

Tags: grpc, quarkus, mutiny

im struggling implementing gRPC communication.
There is one maven project with two modules which should communicate using gRPC.

The classes generated from *.proto-files contains `SessionServiceInterface`, which is in fact a MutinyService-interface. (partial implementation below)

Running both projects results in the following Error:

```
Caused by: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: de.ilem0n.SessionServiceInterface cannot be injected into de.ilem0n.sessions.FlinkSessionReconciler#sessionService - only Mutiny service interfaces, blocking stubs, reactive stubs based on Mutiny and io.grpc.Channel can be injected via @GrpcClient
```

The Error itself says that 'only Mutiny service interfaces [...] can be injected via @GrpcClient'

And now im confused. Am I doing anything basically wrong here or is this a strange behaviour?
Hopefully you have some ideas ;)

The interface
session.proto:

```
syntax = "proto3";

option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_package = "de.ilem0n";
option java_outer_classname = "SessionProto";

package session;

service SessionServiceInterface {
  rpc getSessionInfo(SessionRequest) returns (SessionInfoReply) {}
  rpc createSession(SessionRequest) returns (SessionInfoReply) {}
}

message SessionRequest {
  string sessionId = 1;
}

message SessionInfoReply {
  bool isHealthy = 1;
  string errorMessage = 2;
  string sessionId = 3;
  string dnsName = 4;
  string ipAddress = 5;
}
```

SessionService.java:

```
@GrpcService
public class SessionService implements SessionServiceInterface {
  @Inject KubernetesClient k8s;
  @Inject SessionBootstrapper sessionBootstrapper;

  @Override
  public Uni<SessionInfoReply> getSessionInfo(SessionRequest request) {
    /* ... boring implementation detail ..*/
  }

  @Override
  public Uni<SessionInfoReply> createSession(SessionRequest request) {
    /* ... boring implementation detail ..*/
  }
```

Server-'application.properties':

```
quarkus.http.port=8090

flink.base-image=flink:1.14.2-scala_2.11-java11

operations.namespace=ngbm-gitops
operations.flink.config-map=flink-config
operations.flink.templates-config-map=flink-templates
operations.service-account.name=ngbm-flink-operator-sa
operations.clusterrole-binding.name=ngbm-flink-operator-crb
operations.k8s.default-timeout.value=1
operations.k8s.default-timeout.unit=MINUTES
session.bootstrap.override-namespace=true
session.bootstrap.labels.controlled-by=flink-operator
```

SessionClient.java:

```
public class FlinkSessionReconciler implements Reconciler<FlinkSession> {

    @GrpcClient
    SessionServiceInterface sessionService;

    /* ... boring implementation detail ..*/
}
```

Client-'application.properties':

```
quarkus.grpc.clients.sessionService.host=localhost
quarkus.http.port=8080

default.timeout.value=10
default.timeout.unit=SECONDS

session.bootstrap.timeout.value=10
session.bootstrap.timeout.unit=MINUTES
```

And the pom.xml's:

Project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>de.ilem0n</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-operator</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>16</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>16</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.release>16</maven.compiler.release>
        <compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</compiler-plugin.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
        <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
        <quarkus.platform.version>2.6.3.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
        <surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</surefire-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>resource-handler</module>
        <module>session-sidecar</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-health</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-fault-tolerance</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Client Module:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>de.ilem0n</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-operator</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>resource-handler</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <quarkus-sdk.version>3.0.1</quarkus-sdk.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>de.ilem0n</groupId>
      <artifactId>session-sidecar</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkiverse.operatorsdk</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-operator-sdk</artifactId>
      <version>${quarkus-sdk.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>build</goal>
              <goal>generate-code</goal>
              <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
          <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
          <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-parameters</arg>
          </compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
            <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>native</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>native</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>integration-test</goal>
                  <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
                    <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                    <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                  </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
      <properties>
        <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

Server Project:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <parent>
        <groupId>de.ilem0n</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-operator</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>session-sidecar</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-grpc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-kubernetes-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                            <goal>generate-code</goal>
                            <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-parameters</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                        <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jboss.jandex</groupId>
                <artifactId>jandex-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-index</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jandex</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>native</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>native</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                                        <native.image.path>
                                            ${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner
                                        </native.image.path>
                                        <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
                                        </java.util.logging.manager>
                                        <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
            <properties>
                <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you post your application configuration?

Comment: @Clement Thanks for the hint, of cause an important part. Ive added it to my question below the server and client implementation.

Comment: Using the gRPC API instead of Mutiny it works fine. But that's more a workaround than a solution. (see: https://quarkus.io/guides/grpc-getting-started)

Comment: I(t would be great if you could open an issue with a reproducer on https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues. Michal or I would have a look, as it should work without any issue.

Comment: This can now be tracked under https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/23277

Comment: So, the problem is that the proto file was missing in the client module.

Answer (score 1):

Pre Quarkus 2.8 you need to copy the proto files into the client module. This is not required anymore in 2.8, as you can indicate in which dependency you may have proto files and Quarkus will automatically generate the code from these files.